# How to let a button automatically enter values from the database into a form?

Tags: php, html, ajax, database

This is an image of how the page looks like,

[image]

The 2 big blue buttons at the top are buttons that represent a value from the database. The main function of this button is to help the user to fill in the form in a convenient way leaving only the "Description" to be filled in.

This is my code for the page,

```html
<div class="bodycontainer">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">My Records</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <?php
  require 'dbfunction.php';

  $con = getDbConnect();
  $day = date("l");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
   "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
   $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM timetableschedule WHERE day='" . $day . "'");

   while ($schedule = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="admininfobox">
        <a class="btn btn-primary">
          <?php
  echo "<br/>";
  echo $schedule['academicInstitution'] . "<br />";
  echo $schedule['startTime'] . "-" . $schedule['endTime'] .  "hrs<br />";

  echo "<br/>";
  ?>
        </a>
        </div>
      
      </div>
      <?php
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
 }
 ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Record Activity</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form name="Create New Admin"  class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="handlerecord.php">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Academic Institution</label>
            <input list="AcadInst" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Institution Name" name="academicInstitution">
            <datalist id="AcadInst">
              <option value="Singapore Polytechnic (SP)">
              <option value="Ngee Ann Polytechnic (NP)">
              <option value="Temasek Polytechnic (TP)">
              <option value="Republic Polytechnic (RP)">
              <option value="Nanyang Polytechnic (NYP)">
              <option value="Others (Please specify)"> 
            </datalist>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Level of Teaching</label>
            <input list="LvTeaching" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Teaching Stage" name="levelofteaching">
            <datalist id="LvTeaching">
              <option value="Undergraduate Teaching">
              <option value="Postgraduate Teaching">
              <option value="Continuing Education">
              <option value="Others (Please specify)"> 
            </datalist>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label>Type of Teaching</label>
            <input list="TyTeaching" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Teaching Type" name="typeofteaching">
            <datalist id="TyTeaching">
              <option value="Clinical Teaching">
              <option value="Academic Teaching">
              <option value="Talk">
              <option value="Others (Please specify)"> 
            </datalist>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="startdate">Start Time</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Select Time" name="starttime">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="enddate">End Time</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Select Time" name="endtime">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label for="enddate">Description</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Optional" name="Description">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="submit"  value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">
            </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

An overview of the database,
[image]

I am not sure on how to code it. Like Once the user click onto the button, the button goes through the database and input the data accordingly into the form ready for the user to submit.

Comment: I am unsure on how to code handlerecord.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to create an AJAX request on click.

1. Create a page loadFormData.php

Accept key data to search in database. For eg: id. Then search in database with this  key and get the results. Finally encode this to json (json_encode()) and echo the result.

2. When the user clicks on the button, trigger an ajax (Javascript) function and send the key values to the loadFormData.php

From the returned json result, extract institution name, start time, end time etc and fill this to form fields using JavaScript

```
$("#blueButton").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "loadFormData.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success : function(data) {
            // extract each item from the variable 'data'
      }
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create a form and use action to state the method of entering the values that you want.

For example

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

You can use this to enter the data easily.